# Confused about how generics work with inheritance

Tags: c#

I'm trying to refactor some code at work and I'm running into some issue. Let's say I have the following code (greatly simplified just to illustrate the issue):

An abstract Row class:

```
abstract class Row 
{

}
```

A concrete Row class that extends Row

```
class SpecificRow : Row
{

}
```

An interface that takes a generic type with a method that accepts a ICollection:

```
interface IDbInsertable<T> 
{
   void InsertToDb(ICollection<T> list);
}
```

An abstract class that implements the above interface:

```
abstract class BaseDownloader: IDbInsertable<Row>
{
   public abstract void InsertToDb(ICollection<Row> list);
   //and other unrelated methods...
}
```

A concrete class that extends BaseDownloader:

```
class SpecificDownloader : BaseDownloader 
{
  public void InsertToDb(ICollection<SpecificRow> list)
  {
     //implementation
  }
  //other stuff
}
```

In the SpecificDownloader class, I get the error "SpecificDownloader does not implement inherited abstract member '`BaseDownloader.InsertToDb(ICollection<Row>)`"

What I have tried:

1. Saving all the code and recompiling
2. Change `public void
   InsertToDb()` to `public override void InsertToDb()`, in which case
   the error message becomes 'SpecificDownloader.InsertToDb no suitable
   method found to override'.
3. Restarting Visual Studio

From a theoretical point of view, the above should work fine in my opinion, but it's not letting me compile and I have no reason why.  If I missed something important, please let me know.

Comment: this will fix : abstract class BaseDownloader: IDbInsertable<SpeceficRow>

Comment: Java and C# implement generics in different ways. Please choose one most appropriate langauge tag

Comment: The signature of the method needs to be `InsertToDb(ICollection<Row> list)`, as defined by the abstract class (change SpecificRow to Row)

Comment: hi nVaiD, unfortunate I cannot make that fix as it does not do what I need it to do.  I need BaseDownloader to accept any of kind Row, and not just a SpecificRow

Comment: The interface defines what the class shall do. And the specific downloader cannot do what the interface says. It can do less: only for specific things.

Comment: @Aiyuni Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have after cricket_007's mentioned change. Also include the new error message you get.

Comment: I think `Downloader<T>` might do what you want. Define `T` as `Row` or `SpecificRow`. No need for abstract base classes, inherited classes etc.

Comment: @Thomas, yes. BaseDownloader is abstract, implements IDbInsertable<Row> SpecificDownloader will extend it and use <SpecificRow>.  This is doing less.

Comment: You know that the word *extend* means *doing more*, not *doing less*, do you?

Comment: cricket_007's solution gave me the exact same error. Did not get a new error.

Comment: @ThomasWeller thanks for the suggestion, but I can get the code working fine with less classes like what you suggested, but I want to add more abstraction to the program and figured it would also be a good learning experience.  In theory what I have done should work, but I do not know why it does not work.

Comment: @Aiyuni You have to change the method in the `SpecificDownloader` class. Please [edit] your question to include the new source code you have based on the comment and answer from cricket_007.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make BaseDownloader a generic class. and add a type constraint that forces T to be a type of row. Like this

```
//Class implements the interface and uses the Generic type T from basedownloader. And that has the type constraint
abstract class BaseDownloader<T> : IDbInsertable<T> where T : Row
{
    //This forces T to always be a type row
    public abstract void InsertToDb(ICollection<T> list);
    //and other unrelated methods...
}
```

And then when inheriting from basedownloader specify the type of row you desire.
Like this

```
//Class now gives specificrow as the generic type when inheriting from basedownloader
class SpecificDownloader : BaseDownloader<SpecificRow>
{
    //Now InsertToDb has a collection of SpecificRow instead of just row
    public override void InsertToDb(ICollection<SpecificRow> list)
    {
        //implementation
    }
    //other stuff
}
```

More on [generic type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)